# Generating video with Flash Player and Wowza Media Server

Tags: flash, actionscript, video, wowza

I'm currently creating a whiteboard in Flash, and I want to be able to record all of the user interaction for later playback. Is it somehow possible to create a video of what the user is drawing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared objects to store user interactions. Then you can play it back by reconstructing user-actions from shared objects.

Comment: Yes, I'm already taking this approach, but what I'm really looking for is a way to generate a video that someone could download and replay locally.